# How to find the parent of a group of elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this markup:

```
<div class="some_container">
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Is there anyway for me to query for the parent of a collection in jQuery (or javascript) with a rule that basically means:

```
Return the parent element that contains 4 or more <p> tags
```

Or

```
Return a collection of all <p> tags with 4 or more siblings
```

... and then I can call `.parent()` on it?

I cannot simply search by the `<div>` since it is variable in my use case (different ids, classes, sometimes not even a `<div>` as the container). I need a way to find a group of related elements, then find the parent of that collection. Is this possible?

Comment: You need some way to relate the elements otherwise there might be more than one parent. What if there were two containers that both had at least four `<p>` elements?

Comment: @nnnnnn Using @MrOBrian's answer, you can loop over the collection and build an array of parents with jQuery's `$.each`. Either way, I want all containers on the page that have 4 or more `<p>`'s, so I'm satisfied. :)

Comment: Yes, sure, you can build an array. I just wanted to make sure you realised that you might need to...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nth-of-type might be what you're looking for.  Something like:

```
$("p:nth-of-type(4)").parent()
```

That would grab a collection of elements that each have at least 4 paragraph elements.

Comment: It does indeed work on older versions of Internet Explorer; jQuery provides fallbacks for such selectors.

Comment: @Charmander Ah, my bad, I was thinking of CSS selectors rather than in terms of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('p').siblings('p').length > 4) 
{
     // Yay!!!
}
```

Comment: As I said in my post, I don't know `.some_container`, so I can't query against it.

Comment: ah, missed that. Edited for you

Comment: This doesn't feel like it would have good performance, as I'd have to cross-check every `p` in the DOM.

Comment: Actually 25% faster than your accepted answer. Use console.time() to verify:
console.time("someKey");
console.log($('p').siblings('p').length);
console.timeEnd("someKey");

Comment: Wow, really? Why is that, do you know? Would that vary based on the JS engine?

Comment: Would definitely vary by browser, and I'm guessing would be even better in browsers that don't natively support nth-child() like IE<8

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13640/discussion-between-neezer-and-joecortopassi)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is too performant but it is much faster than finding all the `p` tags and checking siblings:

```
var parents = $("div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('p').length > 4;            
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for me either, since I don't know that my container will always be a `div` (as I said in my post).